# pandas dataframe from list of tuples [(column, row, value)]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of tuples `my_list = List[Tuple[int, int, float]]` where the first number refers to a row, second to the column, and the third to the coordinate value. (Basically, this is a matrix style.

```
# the columns start from any number  
my_data = [(1,100,0.1), (1,101,0.2), (1,103,0.1), 
           (2,100,0.3), (2,101,0.1), (2,103,0.1)
]
# output 
#    100  101  103  
# 1  0.1, 0.2, 0.1 
# 2  0.3, 0.1, 0.1
```

How to create a `pd.DataFrame` from such a list? Thanks!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(my_data).pivot(0,1,2)`?

Comment: The brackets you've left around each row in the output make it look like you want each row to remain a list.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, @AnuragDabas that's what I was looking for!